# Multi-Threaded Java HTTP-Server

Tags: java, com.sun.net.httpserver

I use `sun.net.httpServer` to run an HTTP-server in my application (don't ask me why).

The thing is it processes my requests in just one thread so my throughput is a disaster.

I thought if I `setExecutor` to my `httpServer` this problem would be resolved but I started to get exception both on my server-side and client-side (SOAP-UI). I test all kinds of executors including `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` , `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`, `Executors.newWorkStealingPool`, `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` without any luck.

As I said my code works fine when I `setExecutor` to `null` but in this configuration, my code process requests sequentially.

I don't know what to do. Here is my code:

```
public class HTTPListener {
    private HttpServer httpServer;
    private int port = 1253;

    public void stop() {
        if (httpServer != null) {
            httpServer.stop(0);
            httpServer = null;
        }
    }
    public void startHTTPServer() {
        try {
            httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(1252), 100);
            httpServer.setExecutor(null);
            httpServer.createContext("/", new RequestHandler());
            httpServer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

when I set Executors I get this error

```
java.io.IOException: stream closed
    at sun.net.httpserver.FixedLengthOutputStream.write(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:68)
    at sun.net.httpserver.PlaceholderOutputStream.write(ExchangeImpl.java:444)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
    at com.RequestHandler.sendResponse(RequestHandler.java:61)
    at com..RequestHandler.handle(RequestHandler.java:18)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:645)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my RequestHandler Class:

```
public class RequestHandler implements HttpHandler {
    private HttpExchange sender;

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
        this.sender = httpExchange;
        try {
            String request = readRequestBody();
            sendResponse(200, "Hello World !");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            this.sender.close();
        }
    }

    private String readRequestBody() throws Exception {
        try (InputStream isr = sender.getRequestBody()) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[isr.available()];
            isr.read(buffer);
            return Arrays.toString(buffer);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void sendResponse(int httpResponseCode, String response) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            sender.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            sender.sendResponseHeaders(httpResponseCode, response.length());
            outputStream = sender.getResponseBody();
            outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null)
                outputStream.close();
        }

    }
}
```

And I also get this error codes on Client-Side

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 13; received: 0
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:247)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:291)
    at Business.HTTPHandler.Client.send(Client.java:68)
    at main.Main.lambda$main$1(Main.java:86)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at Business.HTTPHandler.Client.send(Client.java:67)
    at main.Main.lambda$main$1(Main.java:86)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid header: *
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeaders(AbstractMessageParser.java:232)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:268)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    ... 5 more

    Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid header: 13
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeaders(AbstractMessageParser.java:232)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:268)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: You set the executor to `null`. Why would you think that does anything except cause problems? If you tested actual executors, then you would have to tell which exceptions you started getting.

Comment: @Kayaman setting the executor to null creates a default executor according to doc, what is the exception you're getting

Comment: Your problem is in the `RequestHandler` class, so that's what you need to show.

Comment: @Kayaman,@Karim I've updated my question guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `RequestHandler` class is not thread safe, that's why it works when you're running single threaded and fails when using an executor.

Do **not** store the `HttpExchange` object in the `sender` variable. It causes a race condition when all threads are overwriting the same variable, and *may* see the wrong object in the wrong state (e.g. one with streams closed already).

You can pass it as a parameter to your methods instead. You really don't need the extra variable.